# Congratulations! You're about to graduate... with a twist

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, moderation

I wanted to pass on the announcement that this site has been cleared for graduation… congratulations!

Graduation comes with it some perks — a listing in the footer of the other sites, you can start migrating content to and from this site, we have things like "community promotional ads" which are only available to graduated sites… you finally get to lose that "beta" label *(yay!)* — and most notably, you can have your first election of moderators which we are [currently a bit short on for this site](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

Unfortunately, there has been a long backlog of sites waiting for their custom site design, and that has kept us from graduating many communities when they were ready **…until now.**

We are going to try a new workflow where we are essentially graduating this site *before* the design is ready. Graduation will work exactly the same in every other way, but we don't yet have [an ETA for when your design will be finished](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247779/98786). We felt it unreasonable to continue holding you back while we catch up on that backlog, so we're going for it!

This is just a heads up that you are in the developer queue to throw that switch. The first indication that you have finally graduated will be the removal of that "beta" label *(yay!)* Beyond that, hopefully everything goes smoothly. We're not anticipating any problems, but since this is a new workflow, I just want to give you that heads up in case anything doesn't seem to go as smoothly as we've become accustomed to.

Congratulations again… and enjoy!

Comment: " a listing in the footer" - there are a bunch of graduate site which I can't find in the footer. e.g. [biology.se], [chemistry.se] and [movies.se].

Answer (score 1):

Seems that Network Engineering Stack Exchange will soon celebrate its first anniversary. Great!