# Can we have a third moderator again?

Tags: discussion, support

We're down to two of us. I've been trying to stop by more often to keep up with the review queues, and Mike P has been very busy flagging via normal, non-moderator powers. But as the site traffic continues to go up, I'm concerned about being able to keep up!

Can the powers that be, reach out to the community and appoint someone to be a third (or even a fourth :^)?

...or are we about to have a community moderator election as part of our (hopefully) impending graduation from Beta?

Answer (score 7):

We are aware of the shortfall, but rather than simply appointing another Pro Tem, we decided it was time to have a full community election! That is the first step following graduation — [Congratulations! You're about to graduate](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/congratulations-youre-about-to-graduate-with-a-twist).

As a pleasant surprise, we managed to get your site design finished way sooner than originally anticipated, so we will be pitching your design (very very shortly) as part of your graduation process. Stay tuned!

Comment: I understand this stance and would normally agree with it. However, Craig is often not on the site in weeks at a time, leaving me the only active mod. While I can stop in most days for at least a little bit, I cannot do so every day. We are now a month past this answer, we haven't moved out of beta yet or started the election, and haven't heard when the redesign will be ready. If we aren't able to throw the "graduation switch" soon, you may want to reconsider this decision and select another Pro Tem, even if it is only for a fairly short time.

Comment: @MikePennington That should not be necessary. We should have had an election months ago. It's crazy that it's taking this long. I will push this forward and make sure it is scheduled in the next week or two. My apologies for letting this go on for so long.